# SQLite, PHP PDO: setting foreign_keys ON

Tags: sqlite, pdo, foreign-keys

Is there way to set SQLite foreign keys ON using PDO SQLite driver options:

```
new PDO('sqlite:...',array(driver options))
```

or using PDO::setAttribute() method?

Answer (score 1):

Just execute `PRAGMA foreign_keys = on` like any other SQL command.

Comment: It's annoying to execute a separate query every time I need to delete or update some table..

Comment: You should try to keep one connection open (if possible).

Comment: You mean persistent connection? Otherwise extra query will be executed even if I don't use DELETE or UPDATE query.